# Wrong number of arguments when using Squeel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, squeel

First, I do simple squeel testing in the Rails console.

```
User.where{name == "abc"}
```

There is no problem for new-created Ruby project

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = 'abc' => []
```

However, when I apply it on my existing project, it gives me error message:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > User.where{name == "abc"}
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)  from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/parse_resource-1.7.3/lib/parse_resource/query.rb:11:in `where'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/parse_resource-1.7.3/lib/parse_resource/base.rb:243:in `where'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

The most-related issue I found is [Squeel issue #193](https://github.com/ernie/squeel/issues/193).

It says that Squeel is not loaded. But, in my case, new-created can be implemented in the same machine.

Anyway, I try to change active_record.rb as it stated, but the problem is still here for my existing project.

I'm using Ruby-1.9.3-p125, Rails v3.2.6, and Squeel 1.0.14.

Comment: Your Rails & Ruby versions are both out-of-date and newer versions have important security fixes. You should upgrade to the latest versions as soon as possible.

Comment: Ture and I will do it later on. But actually I am restricted by Heroku, a cloud sevice. I have to follow its ruby version to ensure my website is work.

Comment: Is there possible conflict between gems, parse_resource and squeel?

Comment: Same problem, posted to github: https://github.com/ernie/squeel/issues/206

Answer (score -1):

Well instead of using where clause you can use:

```
User.filter(:name => 'abc').first
```

This might work in your case

Comment: > NoMethodError: undefined method `filter' for User:Class

Comment: Does not appear to be a method